# Passing of parameter from Database1-Agent to Database2-Agent using Lotusscript

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

I would like to ask if it is possible to pass parameters (for example: fieldA and fieldB value) from Database1 using an agent, and triggering Database2-agent to accept the parameter being passed?

Not sure if it's possible. Thank you!

Comment: Is there a reason why you can’t simply call the 2nd agent as a function from the 1st agent?

Comment: Another approach would be to just create an agent in database2 and access the data in database1 directly from there. This might be much easier and resilient.

Comment: And another one: send database2 a mail. Fully documented… ;-)

Comment: Hi @D.Bugger, may I ask how is it being done?

Comment: Hi @KnutHerrmann, the client does not want to do that kind of approach. They want the agent-to-agent scenario.

Comment: How it's done? I will create a short article on my website and post a link.

Comment: The general idea: send a mail with a command to a target database, specified by a Mail-In Database document. See https://www.bosman.fr/articles/agent-to-agent-communication

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a -partly undocumented- function to pass a complete in- memory document to an agent without saving it. Like that you can pass anything from one agent to another. But it only works if one agent calls the other:

```
Dim ses as New NotesSession
Dim db2 as NotesDatabase
Dim agent2 as NotesAgent
Dim docTemp as NotesDocument

Set db2 = New NotesDatabase( "Server", "db2Path.nsf" )
Set agent2 = db2.GetAgent( "NameOfAgent2" )

Set docTemp = New NotesDocument( db2 )

docTemp.Parameter1 = "Some string"
docTemp.Parameter2 = "Another String"
docTemp.AnyNameYouWant = 3

Call agent2.runWithDocumentContext( docTemp )
```

Then in the agent two you access the document like:

```
Dim ses as New NotesSession
Dim docTemp as NotesDocument

Set docTemp = ses.DocumentContext

param1 = docTemp.Parameter1
param2 = docTemp.Parameter2
numParam1 = docTemp.AnyNameYouWant
```

Comment: Thank you for this, Tode! Helped me big time.

Comment: Hello Tode, may I ask if it's possible to just pass parameters from Agent1 of Database 1 to Agent2 of Database 2? Apparently, the client does not like the idea of having temporary documents being created. They want an agent-to-agent with parameters approach.

For example: Agent 1 will loop through the view, see which matches the condition, retrieves the information from the document: Name, Age, and then pass it on to Agent 2 for processing in Database 2.

Comment: This is not possible. Why don't you implement all in Agent2 in Database2? Your approach is unnecessarily complicated...

Comment: I agree, "the client does not like the idea" isn't really a valid argument in the discussion. Nothing wrong with the temporary document: it is just an in-memory document, it isn't even necessary to save it into the database!